# How do I take data out of a notepad file and place it into a user defined function?

Tags: c++, file-io, user-defined-functions

My professor gave us an assignment where we have to take a data file and that has information about a phone company and wants us to take the call minutes and find the final charge. I'm pretty sure my function is okay but he didn't really explain how to extract information from a data file. (His examples were very simple).

The columns in the file represent the phone number, company code, local minutes, and long distance minutes respectively. This is the order I made my parameters in my function.

My Code:

```
int main()
{

    int pNumber;
    char company;
    int localMin;
    int longMin;

    ifstream infile;
    ofstream outfile;

    infile.open("e:/C++/Lab Assignments/Lab 6/phoneData.dat");
    outfile.open("e:/C++/Lab Assignments/Lab 6/companyComparison.bat");

    while(!infile.eof())
    {
        if(pNumber > 111000)
            **infile >> companyA(int pNumber, char company, int localMin, int longMin); **
    }

    infile.close("e:/C++/Lab Assignments/Lab 6/phoneData.dat");
    outfile.close("e:/C++/Lab Assignments/Lab 6/companyComparison.bat");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting an error in the while loop in my main function. I put double asterisks around the code line in question. I'm just not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please assemble the code-fragments into a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). hardly anyone will like having to solve a code puzzle prior to helping you with your homework code.

Comment: Isn't a "notepad file" just a regular text file?

Comment: @Namit Feel free to accept the answer, if it answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

You don't "place" data into a function, you pass them. That's what function parameters are for. Besides that,

```
companyA(int pNumber, char company, int localMin, int longMin);
```

is a function declaration, which does not have a place here at all.

Here's the edited code that uses the variables you declared, and does not use [`std::basic_ios::eof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/eof):

```
// read to intermediate variables
while(infile >> pNumber >> company >> localMin >> longMin) 
{
    if(pNumber > 111000)
        // just call the function, passing intermediate variables
        companyA(pNumber, company, localMin, longMin);
}
```

Moreover, `std::basic_fstream` does not have a `close` that takes some arguments (path). See the [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/close) and pay attention in the class.

Comment: `infile >> companyA(...)` doesn't make sense. Shouldn't it just be the function call?